# android:screenOrientation

Tags: java, android

Можно ли в файле манифеста указать android:screenOrientation для всего приложения единожды и не прописывать его для каждой активности, если да, то как?

Comment: Активити только одна, все остальное фрагменты.

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, фрагменты и активности - разные вещи, в андроид проектах может быть несколько активностей и/или несколько фрагментов. В данный момент меня интересуют именно активности.

Answer (score -2):

Все таки подготовиться надо хоть чуть-чуть. На всех учебных ресурсах это показано.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"> // вот это
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Ой сорян. Не сразу понял вопрос.